# noob issue about knockout.js and scope

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

followed the docs, tried my own and bump into some problem.

```
initializeViewModel = function(){

    var listing_model = {
        sale_rent: ko.observable( jQuery('#id_sale_rent')),
        property_type: ko.observable( jQuery('#id_property_type').val()),
        address: ko.observable( jQuery('#id_address')),
        is_condo: ko.computed(function(){
            return this.property_type() == 'condominium';
        }, this)
    };



    listing_model.district = ko.computed(function(){

        return this.district() || this.property_type();
    }, listing_model);

    return listing_model;
}
```

The statement `return this.property_type() == 'condominium';` causes an exception `object <object> has no method property_type()`. I think this might be a scoping issue, but `this` seems to be referring to the right instance here. Can someone please point out my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest solution is to use an anonymous function (to create a closure) rather than a plain object:

```
initializeViewModel = function(){
    var listing_model = new function() {
        // Close-in a reference to this object
        var self = this;

        self.sale_rent = ko.observable( jQuery('#id_sale_rent') );
        self.property_type = ko.observable( jQuery('#id_property_type').val() );
        self.address = ko.observable( jQuery('#id_address') );

        self.is_condo = ko.computed(function() {
            return (self.property_type() == 'condominium');
        });
    }();

    // ...
```

Otherwise, "this" inside the function (that defines the computed) refers to whatever you're passing as the second parameter to ko.computed() - the value of the "this" there is the current context that "initializeViewModel" is executed in, so if you're calling that function as usual (i.e. `initializeViewModel()`), "this" will just be a reference to the global object and not to "listing_model" (as expected/intended).

The example in the manual differs from you're code: you're creating a plain object right away while in the manual everything is wrapped in a function. Calling that function with the "new" keyword creates a new object and sets the context ("this") to this object. That's why their code works.

Comment: Question.. Why doesn't my error message in chrome pass the this as domwindow then?

Comment: Sorry, can you please rephrase that? Where do you expect "this" to be the domwindow object?

Answer (score 0):

Well the `this` is referring to the anonymous function scope, and secondly `this.property_type()` is a function call you can't assign a variable to that.

Comment: well i followed the instructions in the docs http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html its says passing the this as a parameter to ko.computed refers to the listing_model object itself,